# VSTS Devops deployed failed rollback to previous version with web and database?

Tags: .net, azure-devops, devops

Devops automatic rollback to the previous version when deployed failed(Web & Database)

I have installed the **Release Management Utility** Tasks extension in your account, you’ll see a task called “**Rollback powershell**” in the task

I have tried to below "Rollback PowerShell" code, but not working.

```
try
{    
$jsonobject = ConvertFrom-Json $env:Release_Tasks

}
catch
{
Write-Verbose -Verbose “Error parsing Release_Tasks environment variable”
Write-Verbose -Verbose $Error
} 
foreach ($task in $jsonobject | Get-Member -MemberType NoteProperty)
{ 
$taskproperty = $jsonobject.$($task.Name) | ConvertFrom-Json
Write-Verbose -Verbose “Task $($taskproperty.Name) with rank $($task.Name) has status $($taskproperty.Status)”
// Perform rollback action required in case $task.Name has status failed   
}
```

This method is correct? if any other way?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The method is correct.As the document mentions:

> "Release_Tasks" environment variable shall be set by the task to make
>   the execution status of each of the tasks in the deployment job
>   available for the powershell script.

May i want to know did you add the variable [System.Debug](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=batch) for output the debugging info. If you set the System.Debug as ture for the release pipeline, you can find the log when the tasks are running.

```
try
{    
    Write-Verbose -Message "1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111"
    Write-Verbose -Message “$env:Release_Tasks”
    Write-Verbose -Message "2222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222"
    $jsonobject = ConvertFrom-Json $env:Release_Tasks
    Write-Verbose -Message "3333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333"

}
catch
{
    Write-Verbose -Verbose “Error parsing Release_Tasks environment variable”
    Write-Verbose -Verbose $Error
} 
foreach ($task in $jsonobject | Get-Member -MemberType NoteProperty)
{ 
    $taskproperty = $jsonobject.$($task.Name) | ConvertFrom-Json
    Write-Verbose -Verbose “Task $($taskproperty.Name) with rank $($task.Name) has     status $($taskproperty.Status)”
    // Perform rollback action required in case $task.Name has status failed   
}
```

You will get the debugging info like [Log Info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8XGHO.png). Can you check the logs of the tasks? I'm not sure the meaning of not working in you post. Did it mean the release is failed or the Rollback PowerShell task did not work as you wanted? Please detail the information.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're missing the rest of the code.  You need to add the logic for when the rollback is to be performed:

```
if ($taskproperty.Status -eq  "failed")
{
      $statuscode = "$($taskproperty.Status)"
      Write-Verbose -Verbose $statuscode
}
}
```

Comment: How to add rollback logic and tell any logic?